Script for selfhosted shell runner in GitLab
I have a pretty naive question about the conceptional difference between following two alternatives for .gitlab-ci.yml file setting up a CI job of a GitLab project. Firstly, the runner configuration file config.toml file is configured as follows in order to have shell as executor:
[[runners]]
  name = "TestRunner"
  url = Blabla.com
  token = xxxxxxxxxxxxxx
  executor = "shell"
  shell = "powershell"

Now the question is what is systematically the difference between the job task
stages:
  - StageA
testjob:
  stage: StageA
  script:
    - echo %AGlobalVar%     \\some global variable, eg PATH
    - mkdir blabla
  tags:
    - TestRunner

vs if I replace the "script" part by
  script:
    - cmd /c echo %AGlobalVar%
    - cmd /c mkdir blabla

The job is intended to run on windows as local machine,  shell is choosen as executor and as shell parameter "powershell", (...or can also be choosen to be "pwsh" or "bash" (if available)). What is the systematical difference between if I invoke shell commandos "directly" (like in first version), or if I "wrap" them via detour through cmd command as in second version?
So the question is what's the essential difference from viewpoint of GitLab philosophy on concept of runner if I put in script part above a line of type

- (some shell command)

,or if I precompose it by the cmd:

- cmd /c (some shell command)

A naive guess of mine is that this may have to do with that GitLab not sees cmd.exe as a shell object itself but just a command of the shell - this conjecture is backed by that the "cmd" option for shell parameter is not available as option for "shell" in config.toml. But not sure if that's exactly the point, just a naive guess.
